# HTML DIV Set axis to bottom for children elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, axis

When elements are defined within a parent `DIV` they positionate from top to bottom. Even if you are using Javascript to append/prepend elements to a parent `DIV` they will keep this rule. I need to do this but with the axis set to the bottom of the parent's `DIV` so when I append/prepend an element, it positionates from **bottom to top**. I obviously can do this with absolute positioning but I'm looking for a solution with relative positioning.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the css `column-reverse`:

```
display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
-webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse; /* Safari 6.1+ */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/h3fhmp8e/3/